# Clean Architecture: get instance in inner circle of class from outer circle

Tags: java, object-oriented, architecture, clean-code

This might be an easy question for experienced software engineers.

I'm currently reading the book [Clean Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134494164) by Uncle Bob, and I'm trying to implement clean architecture in a Java project.

Now, in my project, I came across the exact same situation as described here in Chapter 17 of the book:

[image]

The red line is the boundary between the high-level business rules component and the low-level database component. Thanks to the `DatabaseInterface`, that is part of the high-level component, but implemented in the low-level component, the dependency rule is satisfied.

**However, how can the `BusinessRules` get an instance of an object that implements `DatabaseInterface` without violating the dependency rule?**

The implementing class `DatabaseAccess` is in the low-level component, and the high-level component is not supposed to know anything about the classes in the low-level component.

In other words, we can't instantiate a `DatabaseAccess` object inside `BusinessRules`, because this would violate the dependency rule.

How is this problem generally solved?

**Note:**

The same situation is also described in Chapter 18:

[image]

And here again, how can `Client` get an instance of `ServiceImpl` without violating the dependency rule?

The book doesn't give any hints about how this is done in practice. I would be very interested to know what's the correct strategy for solving this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your application structure should have one "Entry point" component(with `main` method), which will "know" about all other components/libraries.
Responsibility of entry point component will be to glue together high-level abstractions and low-level implementations.

```
.----------------.       .----------------<I>-.       .-----------------.   
| Business rules | ----> | Database interface | <|--- | Database access |  
'----------------'       '--------------------'       '-----------------'  
        ^                         ^                            ^  
        |                         |                            |  
        |                         |                            |  
        |                  .-------------.                     |  
         ----------------  | Entry point |  -------------------  
                           '-------------'
```

In entry point you can instantiate business rules objects and pass database interface implementations without business rules to know about implementation details.

```
public void main()
{
    // MyDatabase implements IDataAccess
    IDataAccess dataAccess = new MyDatabase(connectionString); 

    // BusinessRules expect an instance of IDataAccess as constructor parameter
    MyBusinessRule rule = new MyBusinessRule(dataAccess);
}
```

This approach is well known as Dependency injection. There are a bunch of Dependency injection frameworks exists which will automate this process. But for sake of learning will be good to do it manually and solve possible problems by yourself.

Comment: I got it! Now I think I finally understood dependency injection, after several years of first hearing about it. In your above diagram, the middle box should be `DatabaseInterface`, right?

Comment: @weibeld, correct, fixed diagram.

Comment: "the Main is the dirtiest class."  Bob does mention this,  but your example does clarify it a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach is to use some kind of factory (Wikipedia: Factory Method Pattern).  Your high level code requests an object from the factory, and the factory knows from which concrete class the object has to be created.

Edit: The implementation of the factory (not its interface) is specific to the application, it is part of the configuration.  It "glues" together business logic and lower layer, but is not part of either one.

The factory approach is useful if the decision, when and how often objects of the lower layer need to be constructed is in the business logic.  In other cases, other inversion of control mechanisms can be used, like, providing the business logic the objects during business logic startup (see answer from Fabio).

Comment: Thanks. What about dependency injection? Could this be another approach to solve the same problem?

Comment: In which layer this kind of Factory should exists? It cannot be in Business rules layer, because then Business rules should "know" about low-level implementation.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing. If this factory is part of the high-level business rules component, then this component as a whole would still have dependencies on the low-level implementations (which violates the dependency rule). On the other hand, if the factory is part of a low-level component, then the high-level business rules component would have a dependency on this low-level component since it uses the factory (which violates the dependency rule).

Comment: So, it seems that it is dependency injection that goes very well together with Inversion of Control/Dependency Inversion, which is the backbone of Clean Architecture.

Comment: @Fabio: The factory interface exists in business rules layer, the factory implementation (at least the part that contains the knowledge about which object to construct) belongs neither to business layer, nor to the lower layer.  It is in fact part of the glue of the system (configuration) - similar to what you call entry point in your answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  The factory still needs to know the implementation and the BusinessRules would need to know the factory. So again the Dependancy rule would be violated.